functor is right exact if and only if it preserves quasi-isomorphisms between projectives
In pursuit of finding how homotopical algebra is a generalisation of homological algebra, I want to compare the requirement to define left/right derived functors.
Let $A$ be an abelian category with enough projectives. In homological algebra, an additive functor $A\rightarrow \text{Ab}$ admits a left derived functor if it is right exact. On the other hand, the induced functor $C^+A\rightarrow C^+\text{Ab}$ on positively graded chain complexes admits a left derived functor (in the sense of Quillen in his book $\textit{Homotopical algebra}$, using the projective model structure) if it preserves quasi-isomorphisms between chain complexes consisting of projective objects.
My goal is to prove or disprove that these conditions are equivalent. In other words, a functor $A\rightarrow \text{Ab}$ is right exact if and only if the induced functor $C^+A\rightarrow C^+\text{Ab}$ preserves quasi-isomorphisms between projective objects.
I would love to see anyone's take on this problem, as my attempts to relate these two concepts have failed miserably. I would also appreciate  it if someone shares of a book that treats a topic similar to this.
